# Blazor : Missing Authorization Header when reloading a page

Tags: jwt, local-storage, blazor

I have an issue with the authorization header in a Blazor app.
I manage to Login and use different pages that execute api request to fetch some data but the issue comes whenever I want to reload a page.

When hitting the link in the menu and getting to "https://localhost:44387/MyExerciseTemplateBanks/", the data is fetched and showed (If I click another page and come back also) :

```
:authority: localhost:44387
:method: GET
:path: /api/ExerciseTemplateBanks
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-BE,fr;q=0.9,en-BE;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5
authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJlNGMwNWY2ZC05M2Q0LTRiMDctODJjZS03ZWZiYzUyZTEwMGUiLCJqdGkiOiIwYTY5NzQ1NS1kNjBlLTQwYzMtODI0YS1lYWNkMjc5NTI5YmMiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Ik1yQXRvbWUiLCJyb2xlIjpbIkR1bW15IiwiVEVBQ0hFUiJdLCJQZXJtaXNzaW9ucyI6IlxuXHUwMDBiXGZcclx1MDAwZVx1MDAwZlx1MDAxMFx1MDAxMVx1MDAxMlx1MDAxM1x1MDAxNFx1MDAxNVx1MDAxNlx1MDAxN1x1MDAxOFx1MDAxOVx1MDAxYVx1MDAxYlx1MDAxY1x1MDAxZFx1MDAxZVx1MDAxZiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD1kaW90eSIsImV4cCI6MTU3NzUyNjM0NywiaXNzIjoibG9jYWxob3N0IiwiYXVkIjoidXNlcnMifQ.FEvwzEoR868oINGVdyedsA8z3Qlx16ENVvvLkRxSIEw
cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8P4mU_JbFqRCn54otwf12q5yA7N68HaG-bobWYp3vyOztrMZVddJea_LhUAXKRcVKyGD3eATQrfSqtp7_ruRNrtujaFHdGJYTfE-RsOGmm9MschC_eTNzJfC13U4J7IlxNgO6J578tm_3DG8WnmxFjg2H7qQJJm1IYHt8OY49TqFpjCWpvQVkiAvf4iUmjO6CXJrRWwYQoDM65NRXtJtbcVE0zzA12r2E15WLMMOb6DMGwMpGA5DsU1zuXMY83f0ZBUmlnXBb4xYbPSICwKX-RxAnSJZYp7dYfHmx08_fbnQzQ_1FgMGcZSrf_TxRnFuxMh6o1YYMxkgnScZ4sWiIJIfFBIEJdXuyUKjRyEKH8vczojfFsGLDLoCcBSumSRMxAWV_2wm6rHT6OhEQLlYFWwlJdlqgMz0ZzwcVnqijkznystakHngxQNdJjjVVrt9uQwNi1SaOl2pvh0g0RqjPT0jbkU5BeO7XJ_pWRNK7bs2G4LMaFSt14M45-PerDKD6nBV6XS_7he3oEZMw49PSjHjQnc6BlKhT_TGj6RrP3RotEz61JSQU8wiCtTpLrGouD-f4FtThQsO4oHCV6r6HzD2WGo9oGm_qbsRnIlB16NbseqsAV-7TVuF2fMfboSVhZj7YFzHDNGLfTqK4yIjkU65qWRHsdPoR5WBLuStBAW1QC1-7nj8H_NjXfEuOhPyzUKR4usBXbYBr6a_PtkGS0I
referer: https://localhost:44387/MyExerciseTemplateBanks/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

But as soon as I type the path in the browser or refresh the page, the authorization header in the request is missing :

```
:method: GET
:path: /api/ExerciseTemplateBanks
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-BE,fr;q=0.9,en-BE;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5
cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8P4mU_JbFqRCn54otwf12q5yA7N68HaG-bobWYp3vyOztrMZVddJea_LhUAXKRcVKyGD3eATQrfSqtp7_ruRNrtujaFHdGJYTfE-RsOGmm9MschC_eTNzJfC13U4J7IlxNgO6J578tm_3DG8WnmxFjg2H7qQJJm1IYHt8OY49TqFpjCWpvQVkiAvf4iUmjO6CXJrRWwYQoDM65NRXtJtbcVE0zzA12r2E15WLMMOb6DMGwMpGA5DsU1zuXMY83f0ZBUmlnXBb4xYbPSICwKX-RxAnSJZYp7dYfHmx08_fbnQzQ_1FgMGcZSrf_TxRnFuxMh6o1YYMxkgnScZ4sWiIJIfFBIEJdXuyUKjRyEKH8vczojfFsGLDLoCcBSumSRMxAWV_2wm6rHT6OhEQLlYFWwlJdlqgMz0ZzwcVnqijkznystakHngxQNdJjjVVrt9uQwNi1SaOl2pvh0g0RqjPT0jbkU5BeO7XJ_pWRNK7bs2G4LMaFSt14M45-PerDKD6nBV6XS_7he3oEZMw49PSjHjQnc6BlKhT_TGj6RrP3RotEz61JSQU8wiCtTpLrGouD-f4FtThQsO4oHCV6r6HzD2WGo9oGm_qbsRnIlB16NbseqsAV-7TVuF2fMfboSVhZj7YFzHDNGLfTqK4yIjkU65qWRHsdPoR5WBLuStBAW1QC1-7nj8H_NjXfEuOhPyzUKR4usBXbYBr6a_PtkGS0I
referer: https://localhost:44387/MyExerciseTemplateBanks/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

My first guess was that there's something related to State Management, but localStorage should persists through a reload right?

Basically, my questions are : 
1. What is happening in blazor client when the page is refreshed
2. How can I be sure that the authorization header will be in the request when refreshing a page consuming an API?

Here's the code related to authentication and authorization in my project :

**AuthService.Login()** is called when submitting the login form :

```
        public async Task<LoginResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var loginAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginModel);
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/Accounts/Login", new StringContent(loginAsJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var loginResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResult>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return loginResult;
        }

        await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("authToken", loginResult.Token);
        ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginResult.Token);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", loginResult.Token);

        return loginResult;
    }
```

**ApiAuthenticationStateProvider :**

```
   public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public ApiAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string token)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }
```

**AccountsController :**

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto) //Former CreateToken (Renamed)
    {

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginDto.Username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDto.Password, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //Create the token
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)

                };

                var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim("role", userRole));
                    var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);

                    if (role == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

                    foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
                    {
                        claims.Add(roleClaim);
                    }
                }

                //
                //Calculate the Permissions Claim value and add it
                claims.Add(new Claim("Permissions", await _rtoPCalcer.CalcPermissionsForUser(user, userRoles)));
                //


                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"])); //
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    _config["Tokens:Audience"],
                    claims,
                    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                    signingCredentials: credentials
                    );
                DateTime expiration = token.ValidTo;

                return Ok(new LoginResult { Successful = true, Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token), ValidTo = expiration });
            }
        }

        return BadRequest(new LoginResult { Successful = false, Error = "Username and password are invalid." });
    }
```

**ExerciseTemplateBanks.razor :**

```
  @using System.Net.Http;
    @using ViewModels.ExerciseModule
    @inject HttpClient Http

@page "/MyExerciseTemplateBanks"

<h3>ExerciseTemplateBanks</h3>
<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (ApiResponse == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    if (ApiResponse != null && ApiResponse.Results.Any())
        foreach (var item in ApiResponse.Results)
        {
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Name : @item.Name</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Text : Bla bla bla</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><a href="/AddExerciseTemplateBank">Create New Bank</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@code {
    private string Response { get; set; }
    private WebApiMessageAndResult<List<ExerciseTemplateBankVm>> ApiResponse { get; set; }
    private List<ExerciseTemplateBankVm> Banks { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ApiResponse = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WebApiMessageAndResult<List<ExerciseTemplateBankVm>>>("api/ExerciseTemplateBanks");

    }
```

**As Enet requested (cf. comments below)** :
I tried adding those two lines of code.

```
        var token = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new authenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
```

But started just by adding the first one and a Console.Writeline(token) and reloading the page works (the authorization header is present).

```cs
 var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
 ApiResponse = await Http.GetJsonAsync<WebApiMessageAndResult<List<ExerciseTemplateBankVm>>>("api/ExerciseTemplateBanks");
```

Does it mean, I'll have to retrieve the token from the header before every Api Request to make sure reloading the page will work?
Would love an explanation, a bit lost out here :o

Comment: Is the data fetched and displayed when you type the path in the browser or refresh the page ? Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.
When I refresh, type the path in a new tab => no authorization in the request header. No data is fetched, I get 401(unauthorized).

Comment: Even if I open a new window, type the path and get 401, then click on a link to the index (clicking on a link to a route where I'm already, does not reload the page), then click to go on a page and fetch data, it works

Comment: In ExerciseTemplateBanks.OnInitilizedAsync try this code and report results... vart token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");  Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token); And then add the call to GetJsonAsync..........

Comment: @Gapwe Have you resolved problem fully?

Comment: @Przemo It's been a while but I remember I did. I probably forgot to put the answer here :/ I could reopen the project if you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` in the constructor from the
`AuthenticationStateProvider` implementation fixed this for me.